# How to Wildcard Or Regex on Multiple Strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of SKU names, and I need to parse out abbreviations into words.

The abbreviations vary in length (2-5 characters) but match the order of the actual word.

A couple examples:

SKU Name: "235 DSKTP 10LB" ----> "Desktop"

SKU Name: "222840 MSE 2oz" ----> "Mouse"

Other notes:

1. SKU names are not all capital letters, though this I know is probably easier to change using the .upper() method
2. List of words I need to match is long (100+ words), so maybe creating a list of words to match a pattern would be most efficient?

I've played around with some regex but to no avail.

Is there a regex pattern similar to d?e?s?k?t?o?p?

Comment: Do you have any mapping between SKU and name? Does *DSKTP* always mean *Desktop*?

Comment: no it doesn't, unfortunately it varies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

data = '''
235 DSKTP 10LB
222840 MSE 2oz
1234 WNE 1L
12345 XXX 23L
RND PTT GNCH 16 OZ 007349012845
FRN SHL CNCH 7.05 OZ 007473418910
TWST CLNT 16 OZ 00733544
'''

words = ['Desktop',
'Mouse',
'Tree',
'Wine',
'Gnocchi',
'Shells',
'Cellentani']

def compare(sku_abbr, full_word):
    s = ''.join(c for c in full_word if c not in set(sku_abbr) ^ set(full_word))
    s = ''.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s).keys())
    return s == sku_abbr

for full_sku in data.splitlines():
    if not full_sku:
        continue
    for sku_abbr in re.findall(r'([A-Z]{3,})', full_sku):
        should_break = False
        for w in words:
            if compare(sku_abbr.upper(), w.upper()):
                print(full_sku, w)
                should_break = True
                break
        if should_break:
            break
    else:
        print(full_sku, '* NOT FOUND *')
```

Prints:

```
235 DSKTP 10LB Desktop
222840 MSE 2oz Mouse
1234 WNE 1L Wine
12345 XXX 23L * NOT FOUND *
RND PTT GNCH 16 OZ 007349012845 Gnocchi
FRN SHL CNCH 7.05 OZ 007473418910 Shells
TWST CLNT 16 OZ 00733544 Cellentani
```

Comment: This seems to work for those cases, but it doesn't work for:RND PTT GNCH 16 OZ 007349012845 as "Gnocchi"

Comment: @tsays Updated my answer.

Comment: How about if the position of the abbreviation is different? For example: FRN SHL CNCH 7.05 OZ 007473418910 as "Shells" does not work.

Comment: @tsays Updated my answer. But it won't be always 100%, I don't know the all combinations of SKUs and abbdreviations (could be anything)

Comment: thank you! for the most part, this is working except for example cases like "TWST CLNT 16 OZ 00733544" does not match "Cellentani". Is the matching of sets (in the 'compare' function) not catching repeat letters?

Comment: @tsays Updated my answer. I changed a little bit how the repeating letters are handled.

Comment: do you know why it doesn't work for SPGHTTI as "Spaghetti"?

Comment: @tsays Because there's two TT in the abbreviation. As I said, nothing will work 100% - because there's unknown number of combinations of abbreviations and words. You can try and remove duplicate characters from the abbreviation.

Comment: gotcha, thank you so much! This solves 90% of my problem, and probably going to apply a 'similar string' function for the remaining 10%

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary that associates the abbreviation with the actual word:

```
import re
names = ["235 DSKTP 10LB", "222840 MSE 2oz"]
abbrs = {'DSKTP':'Desktop', 'MSE':'Mouse'}
matched = [re.findall('(?<=\s)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s)', i) for i in names]
result = ['N/A' if not i else abbrs.get(i[0], i[0]) for i in matched]
```

Output:

```
['Desktop', 'Mouse']
```

Answer (score 0):

Lookup [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) - it measures "similarity for text".

Source of [Levenshtein-Implementation: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation)

> ```
> def levenshtein(s1, s2):
>     # source: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation
>     #               /Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python
>     if len(s1) < len(s2):
>         return levenshtein(s2, s1)
>
>     # len(s1) >= len(s2)
>     if len(s2) == 0:
>         return len(s1)
>
>     previous_row = range(len(s2) + 1)
>     for i, c1 in enumerate(s1):
>         current_row = [i + 1]
>         for j, c2 in enumerate(s2):
>             insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1  
>             deletions = current_row[j] + 1        
>             substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
>             current_row.append( min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
>         previous_row = current_row
>
>     return previous_row[-1]
> ```

Applied to your problem:

```
skus = ["235 DSKTP 10LB","222840 MSE 2oz"]
full = ["Desktop", "Mouse", "potkseD"]

# go over all skus
for sku in skus:
    name = sku.split()[1].lower()       # extract name
    dist = []
    for f in full:                      # calculate all levenshtein dists to full names
                                        # you could shorten this by only using those
                                        # where 1st character is identicall
        dist.append( ( levenshtein(name.lower(),f.lower()),name,f) )

    print(dist)

    # get the minimal distance (beware if same distances occure)
    print( min( (p for p in dist), key = lambda x:x[0]) )
```

Output:

```
# distances 
[(2, 'dsktp', 'Desktop'), (5, 'dsktp', 'Mouse'), (6, 'dsktp', 'potkseD')]

# minimal one
(2, 'dsktp', 'Desktop')

# distances
[(6, 'mse', 'Desktop'), (2, 'mse', 'Mouse'), (5, 'mse', 'potkseD')]

# minimal one
(2, 'mse', 'Mouse')
```

If you have a fixed mapping, sit down and create a mapping dictionary manually once and youre golden until new skus get introduced.